# UV change (why?)

Tags: uv, armature, export, bones, gltf

I am exporting GLTF files it looks like the right (with bone) or left(without bone).

[image]

Comment: You have written "like the right" twice, maybe a mistake?

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by planted?

Comment: I wonder who upvotes a question like that... Why?.. It's unclear, not even formed as a question, no details... It really needs editing and clarification. I think upvoting questions like that devalues the whole voting system and BSE in general, might not be a great deal, but still...